# Error while adding custom field into sale.order in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I will add a custom field into order.sale form, but install module that can show the error variable Field `detail` does not exist

Here is xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<openerp>

<data>

   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="detail_field_in_view">

        <field name="name">New Sale Order field detail</field>

        <field name="model">sale.order</field>

        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>

        <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']/form/group/group/field[@name='price_unit' ]" position="before">

            <field name="detail" />

        </xpath>

        </field>

   </record>

</data>

</openerp>
```

Here is .py code:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class test_res(osv.osv):

    _inherit = ['sale.order','product.product']

    _columns = {

        'detail': fields.text('Detail'),

    }
```

Comment: if below answer solved your problem than don't forget to accept the answer by click on right button near by upvote/downvote symbol. You may take a tour of SO, that will help a lot for easy use of SO site. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add any field in Order line than you need to define that field under `sale.order.line` object. Because in `sale.order,` field `order_line` has one2many relationship with `sale.order.line`

try with this code:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class sale_order_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    _columns = {

        'detail': fields.text('Detail'),
    }
```

Here is xml code:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="detail_field_in_view">

    <field name="name">New Sale Order field detail</field>

    <field name="model">sale.order</field>

    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>

    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']/form/group/group/field[@name='price_unit' ]" position="before">

            <field name="detail" />

        </xpath>

    </field>

</record>
```